# Change diff view in giltlab to atomic instead of whole line

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab highlights diffs by whole line rather than only the small sections that really differ like TFS does. Is there a way to make Gitlab smart highlight down to one char of difference?

current:

string sample = "text";

**string? sample = "sample" + "text"; //whole old line is highlited red and whole new line is highlited green**

.

TFS style:

string sample = "text";

string sample = **"sample"** + "text"; **//only the deleted is highlighted red, the new is highlted green**

Comment: It [does highlight the actual change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQTsv.png) though? Also, Git stores changes per line. Therefore I don’t think it’s appropriate to present it in any other way.

Comment: Correct, it does, thx. Can I change colors of the actual changes, then? I find it hard to notice it when skimming because the color density is so alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitLab already does highlight inline changes it detects:

[image: inline change]

If you feel that the contrast is too low, you can override the color with a user stylesheet. The relevant CSS selectors currently are:

- `.code.white .line_holder .line_content.new span.idiff` (new, green)
- `.code.white .line_holder .line_content.old span.idiff` (old, red)

Additionally, there are other syntax highlighting themes, just replace the start with:

- Dark (`.code.dark`)
- Solarized Light (`.code.solarized-light`)
- Solarized Dark (`.code.solarized-dark`)
- Monokai (`.code.monokai`)
- None (`.code.none`) – Does not have visible inline highlighting by default, but it’s still possible to configure

How to add a user stylesheet depends on the browser you use. You may have to use a browser extension.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thx. I suggest Chrome extension "CSS User" with rgba(240, 230, 120, 1) for old content and rgba(130, 240, 120, 1) for new content.